# Calculate angle of inclination in NE direction

Tags: calculus, derivatives

A man is on the hill in a point $(-100, -100, 430)$, the hill is given by an equation $z=500-0.003x^2-0.004y^2$.
What is the angle of inclination in NE direction? (i guess ne direction on the cartesian plane)
How to do that?

Comment: As you note, it's not perfectly clear what "in NE direction" should mean in Cartesian coordinates, but a reasonable guess would be along the line $y = x$ passing through $(-100,-100)$ in the $xy$-plane.  Take a diectional derivative and convert this slope to an "angle of inclination" via arctangent.

Comment: thus the solution will be $\arctan 1.4$ ?

Comment: At a glance that seems way too steep and the wrong sign.  The directional derivative is taken for $z (x,y) $.

Comment: could you elaborate on that more, i am not sure what am i doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

In the domain of the function $z$ of $x$ and $y$, the partial derivatives are:

$$ \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = -0.006 x $$

$$ \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = -0.008 x $$

If we evaluate the partial derivatives at point $(x,y) = (-100,-100)$, then we get $\partial z/\partial x = 0.6$ and $\partial z/\partial y = 0.8$.

To get the *directional derivative* we take a linear combination of the two partial derivatives (your textbook's notation may be different) using coefficients that are the components of a unit vector in the desired direction $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$, as I would interpret "northeast":

$$ \vec v = (\cos \theta, \sin \theta) = \left(\frac{\sqrt 2}{2},\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}\right) $$

$$ \nabla_v z = 0.6 \cos \theta + 0.8 \sin \theta = 0.7 \sqrt{2} \approx 0.98995 $$

Now $\nabla_v z$ represents the slope of a line lying over $x=y$ through the three-dimensional point $(-100,-100,430)$ on the "hill".  To convert this slope into an "angle of inclination" (the angle it makes with the $(x,y)$-plane), we have to take the arctangent (inverse tangent):

$$ \text{angle of inclination} = \tan^{-1}( 0.7 \sqrt{2}) \approx 0.78035 \text{ radians} $$

So I was perhaps exaggerating about the slope being "way too steep" and certainly wrong about the sign of the slope (uphill, just as you said), but a few details needed to be clarified.